# Using Math.min.apply on a Float32Array

Tags: typescript

I ran into the following issue with a similar example to the code below while converting a JS file into TS:

```
let arr = Float32Array(3)
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
    
let min_value = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
```

In this example, TypeScript would produce an error with the following message:

```
Argument of type 'Float32Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'Float32Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 5 more.
```

Imagining that `arr` is performance sensitive variable which should not be converted to `number[]`, the most obvious solution to trick the compiler into working would be casting the variable instead:

```
let min_value = Math.min.apply(null, arr as unknown as number[]);
```

Is there a specific reason / danger as to why `apply` should not be able to receive a `Float32Array` parameter in this case?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't treat `apply` differently based on the function. It's *always* going to make you pass an array. And because it's TypeScript, and there are types, of course it won't let you pass a Float32Array. That just goes for every function. What if the function you use actually needs a regular array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) states that the `arguments` parameter can be any [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#working_with_array-like_objects).

[Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#typed_arrays) are array-like objects, so they should be accepted by the `apply` method.

Furthermore, the [Math.min](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.min) specification states that its arguments do not even need to be numbers:

> Given zero or more arguments, this function calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the smallest of the resulting values.

Knowing all of the above, what you are trying to do looks correct and it seems like a TypeScript bug.

As for why that is happening, currently the definitions for `Math.min` and `CallableFunction.apply` are as follows:

```
min(...values: number[]): number;

apply<T, A extends any[], R>(
  this: (this: T, ...args: A) => R,
  thisArg: T,
  args: A
): R;
```

<strike>Most likely both these definitions need to be adapted to act according to the standards.</strike>

EDIT: Likely only the `apply` definition needs to be changed to something like:

```
apply<T, A extends Iterable<AT>, AT, R>(
  this: (this: T, ...args: AT[]) => R,
  thisArg: T,
  args: A
): R;
```

*Or to be more correct, `ArrayLike<AT>` should be used instead of `Iterable<AT>`, but for the above to work `ArrayLike` would need to extend from `Iterable`*

Comment: I don't think the TypeScript team is going to change the compiler and add all the edge cases. It's working as intended anyways since you should be converting one type to another to satisfy the types required, even if it's not necessary.

Comment: I don't think the compiler needs to be adapted, but the definitions should. And it is not working as intended, as the types are compatible according to the specs but TypeScript thinks otherwise.

Comment: Well yeah, but that's like saying we should be allowed to pass strings to `slice` for example: https://tsplay.dev/wRl81m While it would be nice in some cases, it's difficult to draw the line where to stop. And then what's the point of using TypeScript if you're allowed to pass whatever like in JavaScript?

Comment: I agree with you on that part, but it changes nothing: `Float32Array` is still an `ArrayLike<number>`, so it should still be correct even if `Math.min` can only receive `number`s.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript-safe way to write this would be:

```
let min_value = Math.min(...arr);
```

Which compiles down to `Math.min.apply(Math, arr);`